# How do I retrieve a Fontello icon's code programatically

Tags: svg, icons, fontello

In the fontello.css file, I can see the code of an icon, such as:

`.icon-user:before { content: '\e811'; }`

It's the `e811` part that I need to retrieve, to embed the icon inside an SVG chart.

I'd like to be able to retrieve the code of all my icons programmatically.
There is a config.json file but this "e811" code is not in it. Here is what is given for that same icon:

```
{
  "uid": "8b80d36d4ef43889db10bc1f0dc9a862",
  "css": "user",
  "code": 59409,
  "src": "fontawesome"
}
```

How do I retrieve the 4-letter code of icons programmatically? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it, the code in the config.json file is a decimal version of the code in the css file. You need to convert it with `code.toString(16)`

For example `(59409).toString(16) == 'e811'`.
Which can also be written `59409..toString(16) == 'e811'` by the way.

**Side note**

Actually the manual conversion of the code is not even necessary, this native javascript function does it for us: `String.fromCharCode(code)`